For what $n$ do there exist non-periodic tilings with rotational symmetry of order $n$?
More precisely, given an integer $n$, does there exist a non-periodic tiling, where there are infinitely many patches within the tiling, of indefinitely large area, with rotational symmetry of order $n$?
Question. For what values of $n$ can we find such tilings?
I have started to work on this problem. From the literature, I found examples for $n=5$ (Penrose tiling) and $n=7$ (Madison's $7$-fold). Then, from my own investigation, I found examples for $8$, $10$, $12$, and $16$.
Here are pictures of these tilings:
$n=5$

$n=7$

$n=8$

$n=10$

$n=12$

$n=16$


I think one of the Penrose constructions generalizes to any n:
start from the action of Z/nZ on Z^n by cyclic coordinate permutations;
choose a 2-dimensional subspace V in the ambient R^n
on which Z/nZ acts irreducibly; and for some d>0 let C be the set of
projections to V of lattice points that are at distance at most d from V.
The tiling is then the Voronoi tiling associated to C
(or the dual Voronoi tiling, or other variations).

I think subrosa does this for even $n$ https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-016-9779-1

Please see in "Equivalence of the generalised grid and projection methods for the construction of quasiperiodic tilings" by Gähler/Rhyner Sect. 8 "Symmetric two-dimensional grids" where you can find the construction very explictly: https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~gaehler/papers/jav19i2p267.pdf.
(By the way, the minimal dimension for embedding a $n$-fold symmetry in a periodic lattice is given by the Euler's totient $\phi(n)$ with e.g. $\phi(5)=\phi(8)=\phi(10)=\phi(12)=4$, so quasiper. tilings of these rotat. symmetries can be obtained by cut and projection from 4-dim. lattices.)

@VilleSalo Please will you re-post your comment as an answer, instead of just a comment? Then I can up-vote it and mark it as correct. As I see it, this is the complete answer to the question.

Jarkko Kari and Markus Rissanen construct such (even a substitutive one), called Sub Rosa, for even $n$ in [1]. ArXiv is https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.01402
The second-named author is Markus Rissanen, who is not a mathematician but an artist. He is credited as the inventor of the tilings in https://dimensiolehti.fi/laatoitusten-geometriaa/
[1] Kari, Jarkko, and Markus Rissanen. "Sub Rosa, a system of quasiperiodic rhombic substitution tilings with n-fold rotational symmetry." Discrete & Computational Geometry 55 (2016): 972-996.

As a follow-up to @villesalo I want to add the following:
Sub Rosa takes care of the case of even $n$, however it leaves open the case of odd $n$. In what follows, I describe in outline method for transforming a Sub Rosa tiling, reducing the rotational symmetry by a factor of two, thus yielding a system of quasiperiodic rhombic substitution tilings with $n$-fold rotational symmetry for any $n$.
I will explain the transformation in two ways. The first way is more intuitive, while the second is more rigorous - yielding actual modified substitution rules of the standard form.
Throughout, we look at the case of $n=5$ to illustrate.
To begin with then, let's talk about the Rose - a central construction in the Sub Rosa system.
The rose looks like this:

While this construction clearly has $10$-fold symmetry, we can transform it into an analogous construction with $5$-fold symmetry as follows (I refer to this as "breaking the rose" )
We pick two petals from the row nearest the center, and the adjacent petal from the next row, which sits between them. Rotate this triplet by 180 degrees around their collective center. Repeat for all the petals in the row nearest the center.
This yields a broken rose that looks like this:

We can now describe a process for generating a broken rose tiling as follows:

Start with a broken rose

Perform the Sub Rosa substitution rule

Identify each rose in the resulting tiling, and break it. Note that when breaking the roses in the tiling, care must be taken to keep the orientation of the broken rose the same for all roses in the tiling.


go back to step 2 and repeat, indefinitely.
To understand what is happening, consider that fact that within each cycle, the symmetry of the rose is broken ( from $10$ down to $5$ ). This means that the resulting tiling will be quasiperiodic with $5$-fold rotation symmetry both for the whole tiling, as well as for patches within the tiling.

Now we are ready to move on and look at a more rigorous procedure. In this procedure, we don't need any special handling - breaking the roses - we just modify the Sub Rosa substitution rule.
The modified rules are as follows:

The complete tiling appears as follows:

